# How to verify that a word is Bold in selenium webdriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application.I have a scenario that a search term becomes bold in some pages so i need to verify whether the search term is Bold or not.
I have tried the following code but i am not able to verify:

```
String colour = driver.findElement(By.className("classname")).getCssValue("color");
if(colour.contains("rgba(46,46,46,1)"))
System.out.println("Term is Bold");
else
System.out.println("Term is not  Bold");
```

Comment: What do you mean by not able to verify??? is there any exception or anything else?? clear it

Comment: and share your HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bold value of a font is expressed using the `font-weight` CSS property

```
String fontWeight = driver.findElement(By.className("classname"))
                              .getCssValue("font-weight");

boolean isBold = "bold".equals(fontWeight) || "bolder".equals(fontWeight) || Integer.parseInt(fontWeight) >= 700;
```