# How to check if a label is bold with Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please find below the sample HTML code:

```
<div class="form-element email-address" id="gmail-address-form-element">
  <label id="gmail-address-label">
  <strong>
  Choose your username
  </strong>
  <input type="text" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"  
  name="GmailAddress" id="GmailAddress" value=""
spellcheck="false">
  <span class="atgmail">@gmail.com</span>
  </label>
```

I need to  verify "Choose your username" label is bold with Selenium WebDriver.
Appreciate if the language used is java.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497379/how-to-verify-that-a-word-is-bold-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: You could just check for the `STRONG` tag and make sure the text is inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify bold appearance of a certain field in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100438/how-to-verify-bold-appearance-of-a-certain-field-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [getComputedStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537339/getting-the-values-of-all-the-css-properties-of-a-selected-element-in-selenium) to get the style of the element.

Use [`font-Weight`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) to check if it is bold or not

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gmail-address-label > strong"));
    String fontWeight = (String) js.
            executeScript(
                    "return getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).getPropertyValue('font-Weight');",
                    element);
    if (fontWeight.trim().equals("bold")) {
        System.out.println("Is Bold");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Bold - " + fontWeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way we can get the **CssValue** of font-weight and check if it is 'bold' or is greater than or equal to 700 or is 'bolder' .Because by all these ways the bold style can be given to the text
Use following code in java

```
 String fontWeight = driver.findElement(By.className("classname"))
                                          .getCssValue("font-weight");

 boolean isBold = "bold".equals(fontWeight) || "bolder".equals(fontWeight) || Integer.parseInt(fontWeight) >= 700;
```

Hope it will help.